# How do I set the interval in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

I'm trying to create a menu of social media icons that slides into and out of the page. The following code works, but it is too fast. It doesn't look like sliding. I think I could adjust the timing using the `setInterval()` method, but I can't get it to work. This is the code so far:

```
var socialMedia = document.getElementById("socialmedia");
var stalkMe = document.getElementById("pleasestalkme");
function SM() {
socialMedia.style.position = "fixed";
socialMedia.style.right = "-330px";
}
SM(); 
stalkMe.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    if (socialMedia.style.right === "-330px") {
    for (i = -330; i <= -30; i++) {
        var j = i +"px";
        socialMedia.style.right = j;
    }
    } else if (socialMedia.style.right === "-30px"){
            for (i = -30; i >= -330; i--){
        var j = i +"px";
        socialMedia.style.right = j;
    }
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: i don't see `setInterval()` anywhere in your code

Comment: Or `setInterfall` either..

Comment: I have tried to add set interval in all possible ways, but it just seems to break the code

Comment: stalkMe.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
 if (socialMedia.style.right === "-330px") {
 for (i = -330; i <= -30; i++) {
  setInterval(function(){
  var j = i +"px";
  socialMedia.style.right = j;
  }, 100);
 }
 } else if (socialMedia.style.right === "-30px"){
  setInterval(function(){
   for (i = -30; i >= -330; i--){
  var j = i +"px";
  socialMedia.style.right = j;
   }, 100);
 }
 }
}, false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at CSS transitions. Basically you just need to change the `right` style from 300px to 0px and using `transition: right 1s;` you would see your element being animated

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Otherwise, you could have a look at jQuery.... (I feel bad).

Comment: Works perfectly with CSS transitions, I wanted to stay away from jQuery since I'm trying to get a grip on basic javascript, but for this I think your right suggesting the CSS way, thanks

Comment: Glad it helped. That's the right choice: better separation of logic and rendering, and much better performances.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to the solution, a word of warning: you actually should **not** use this code snippet. Instead heed the advice of floribon and look into css transitions.

However, if you absolutely must do it the outmoded way:

```
for (i = -330; i <= -30; i++) {
    var j = i +"px";
    socialMedia.style.right = j;
}
```

write

```
var hnd;
i = -330;
hnd = setInterval ( function () {
    var j = i +"px";
    socialMedia.style.right = j;
    i++;
    if (i > -30) {
        clearInterval(hnd); // end activity
    }
}, 50 ); // interval length in ms
```

Comment: couldn't get this to work, but followed your advice to listen to floribon, thanks